# Convert a lists in list to a CSV file by Python

Tags: python, list, csv

I hope to convert the data like `[[2,3,1],[11,2,4],[8,9,14]]` to a CSV file and the format is (numbers in each line are in different columns)

```
line1: 2  3  1
line2: 11 2  4
line3: 8  9  14
```

However, when I use the following codes (`list` is the name of the list should be converted):

```
myfile = open('/Users/user/Desktop/list245.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerow(list)
```

The result is:

`line 1: [2,3,1],[11,2,4],[8,9,14]`. 
Namely, every numbers are in the first line by different groups.

Comment: wr.writerows(your_list_of_list) should do it.https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Pandas Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) to directly convert it into the format you want.

```
import pandas as pd

my_list =  [ [2,3,1] ,[11,2,4], [8,9,14] ] 

df =  pd.DataFrame(my_list)

df.to_csv('out.csv', sep=',', header=None, index=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert list of list to list first.

```
from itertools import chain
row = list(chain.from_iterable([[2,3,1],[11,2,4],[8,9,14]]))
```

Then you can write it to csv file

```
with open('/Users/user/Desktop/list245.csv', 'w') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(row)
```